# How to show a dialog in SAPUI5 triggerd by the controller and not a view event? (Push notification)

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5

In a SAPUI5 controller of a master view I trigger a `oModel.read()` request to read some data (async). This read will be done each time the page will be reached during navigation.

```
onInit: function() {
  var that = this;
  this.getRouter().getRoute("PageName").attachMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);
},

onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
  ...
  oModel.read(....); // this will be done async
  ...
},
```

The app should be normal rendered (with normal binding).

The mentioned read will load some messages from the server and syncs it with a local model. Now in case of a new message a dialog should be shown.

Here is my problem: Where to place the `dialog.open()` call in the controller (what event?) so that the dialog will be shown?

Right now I tried with `onAfterRendering` and there it works for exactly the first call. For further calls I can't see any dialog. If I place the open dialog in the `onRouteMatched` I can see a short flickering.

So the problem is, that opening the dialog should be done after the rest of the application is rendered. But how to reach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I have a hacked solution.
In the `onInit` method of the controller I register to the `onmousemove` event. Each time the mouse will be moved I can check if there is some data to show.

```
this.getView().attachBrowserEvent("mousemove", function(oEvent) {
    this.onCheckForMessages();
});
```

But better solutions are welcome.